# FTP on WIndows Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have a VM-1  on Azure with windows server 2012. I have installed FTP server in this. (FileZilla)

Another VM-2 in different cloud, where a windows service will access a FTP server in VM-1.

Both VMs are in different cloud. In FTP , while listing directories I am getting '425 Cant open data connection for dir listing'

I am using active mode in FTP.

But If I install the windows service in local machine, it is running correctly without any issue in FTP.

Comment: You should post on ServerFault or SuperUser. This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer though this isn't a programming question, because I can help. :)

When a virtual machine is created, a default ACL is put in place to block all incoming traffic other than for RDP and Remote PowerShell connections.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/28/network-isolation-options-for-machines-in-windows-azure-virtual-networks/

You need inbound ports other than 21 for active connections, typically high ports above 1024, if you have port 21 open inbound already then you should use passive (pasv) mode to let the server open a random outbound port first to solve the issue of needing an ACL for other inbound ports.

More info on Active vs Passive and ports: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html